# The best way to collect all Yii model validation errors

Tags: yii, helper

Is there any inline method to collect all validation errors?
Now I'm doing this:

```
$errors = '';
foreach($model->attributeNames() as $attr)
{
    $errors .= $model->hasErrors($attr) ? $model->getErrors($attr) : '';
}
```

I think this is redundant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply use [`getErrors`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#getErrors-detail) without param, it will returns the errors for all attribute.

You could also use [`Chtml::errorSummary`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#errorSummary-detail), it will displays a summary of validation errors for one or several models.

Comment: Tnx, I missed this obvious variant :-/